# Approximate orthogonality between two sets of Hermite functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, asymptotics, orthogonality, perturbation-theory, hermite-polynomials

Consider the set of Hermite functions $\{\phi_{n}(x,\varepsilon_{1})\}_{n}:= A$ defined below.
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:funcs}
  \phi_{n}(x,\varepsilon_{1}) = \frac{\sqrt[8]{1+\big(\frac{2\varepsilon_{1}}{\gamma}\big)^{2}}}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!}}e^{-\Big(\sqrt{1+\big(\frac{2\varepsilon_{1}}{\gamma}\big)^{2}}-1 \Big)\frac{\gamma^{2}x^{2}}{2}}H_{n}\Bigg(  \sqrt[4]{1+\Big(\frac{2\varepsilon_{1}}{\gamma}\Big)^{2}}\gamma x\Bigg).
\end{equation}

These functions form an orthonormal basis for $(L^{2}(\mathbb{R},d\mu)$ where the measure is  $d\mu = \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\gamma^{2}x^{2}}dx$

Now, imagine that we perturb the $\varepsilon_{1}$ dependent function$\sqrt{1+\big(\frac{2\varepsilon_{1}}{\gamma}\big)^{2}}$ slightly in the following way, keeping in mind that this term show up in all of the components of the definition for $\phi_{n}(x,\varepsilon_{1})$, $\phi_{n}(x,\varepsilon_{1})\rightarrow \phi_{n}(x, \varepsilon_{2})$ where $\varepsilon_{2} := \sqrt{(\frac{2\varepsilon_{1}}{\gamma})^{2}+\alpha}$.

Assuming we do such a transformation the new set $\{\phi_{n}(x,\varepsilon_{2})\}_{n}:=B$ is still an orthonormal basis for $(L^{2}(\mathbb{R}, d\mu).$

I would like to know if there are any exact results for the inner product of an element of A and an element of B. i.e.
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_{n}(x,\varepsilon_{1})\phi_{m}(x,\varepsilon_{2})\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\gamma^{2}x^{2}}dx.$$

In the limit where $\alpha$ is neglibible $\varepsilon_{2}\approx \varepsilon_{1}$ and we should have approximate orthogonality between a fixed element $\phi_{n}(x,\varepsilon_{2})$ of B and any $\phi_{m}(x,\varepsilon_{1})$ of set A where $m\neq n$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I hope you'll pardon me, that I changed "Hermit" to "Hermite" twice.

Comment: I can't figure out what the TeX/mathJax problem is... I don't think I myself induced it... Oop, hm, somehow it has healed itself! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your corrections @paul garret.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections @paul garret!